# Can't extract information as key-value pair from ID card using Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Form Recognizer client library for .NET to extract data from a country's national id card. But it seems that it is unable to get the key-value pairs from the card.
I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/dotnet-sdk tutorial.

I have found that there is only one key-value pair and the value array contains
all the labels/texts (both key and value).

[image]

Do I need to follow another way to extract information from id card?
Do I need to train the model with labels using the labeling tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please try training with labels.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the .NET SDK currently supports Form Recognizer v1.0-preview release and does not yet support Form Recognizer v2.0-preview release. Please follow the following quickstart to train with labels - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool